# avoid user to log in in different browsers or system

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web application which is used by different users.What I need to do is avoid same user to log in in different browsers or system.Can anybody help???Thanks in advance.

Comment: just manage one flag into mysql table against this user and always check this flag when same user log in ( even from same browser or different browser or system).

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the answers (ie, the "is logged in flag") have a pretty big problem!! What if something happens to the browser? (machine is formatted, cache/cookies are cleared, etc) Then you've got a user that the server thinks is logged in, but as far as the user is concerned isn't... and won't be able to log in. You'd have to add a timeout, and monitor each request (to reset the timeout).

I'd suggest that you issue new credentials to the user each time they log in. The act of issuing new credentials invalidates the previous ones. The easiest way to do this is to create a (random) token and save that token to a cookie and to the database row. Check the cookie against the database value and ensure it's current.

Note that this is the reverse of the other answers (I'm not clear if it's the reverse of your intention) -- the user isn't prevented from logging in again, but his previous logins are disabled.

**Edit:**

What I've stated in pseudocode:

```
//to authenticate user
if ($user = sql('select * from users where id = ' . intval($_COOKIE['user_id']) && $_COOKIE['token'] == $user['token']) {
    //user is authenticated. the token in their cookie is the same as the token in the db
} else {
    //user is not authenticated. 
}

//to log user in
if ($user = sql('select * from users where  = ' . intval($_REQUEST['user_id']) && $user['password'] == $_REQUEST['password']) {
    //user is authenticated and can be logged in now. the user id they passed and password match (though you'll probably be accepting email address and hasing the password...).
    $token = rand();
    setcookie('user_id', $user['user_id']);
    setcookie('token', $token);
    sql('update users set token = '$token' where user_id = ' . $user['user_id']);
    //now the token in the db has been updated, and only the user that just logged in has it. other instances of this users login don't have it, so can't authenticate
} else {
    //user is not authenticated and can't be logged in
}
```

Despite the fact that that code is a bit more PHP than pseudo, it's not meant to be run as-is. **You need to customize** for your database library, table schema, ensure security (by using md5() on the password, etc). I'm just trying to illustrate the concept.

**Edit:** As described above, the point of this approach is to allow the user to log in again, but invalidate their previous logins. (This is the opposite of not allowing the user to log in a second time.) Either way, the user is only logged in once -- the question is do you allow the first or last. However, from your comments now, it seems like this isn't what you (think) you want.

Trying to prevent the user from logging in a second time is fraught with pitfalls. Starting with the simplest setup, a user logs in, you set a "isLoggedIn" value in the database, and then you don't let them log in again until that value is cleared (pesumably from your logout.php). (This is what others have suggested -- go ahead and mark one of their answers.) What do you do if they can't log out? If they log in from their desktop and then need to log in from the office?

Do you disallow them from logging in? Or maybe your present a "are you sure you want to log in" message and allow them to override their previous login. If so, you need a way to invalidate the previous login. So you're back to my token suggestion. (In this case, use the existence of the token in the db to signify that they're still logged in to a previous session (the equivalent of isLoggedIn), and clear it out when they log out.)

Do you still want to prevent the second logins? Then you can't rely on your user actively logging out. What if they're at the office? Or they log in from their phone and then lose the phone? Or clear their cookies. You'll have to rely on a timeout. Don't make it too long or the user can't log in when they get to the office, and don't make it too short or the user has to log in every time they get a cup of coffee. (Session cookies might help her, but you can't rely on them as many people leave browser windows open for days.)

In this case, every time they hit the page while logged in you update lastActivity in the database. Then you check that lastActivity is >= now() - x minutes. If not, then you log them out. You would have to do the same thing when they try to log in. If lastActivity >= now() - x minutes, you tell them they can't log in.

(You could rely on PHP sessions, but I have to admit I don't have enough experience with configuring these to recommend anything. I looked for a handler to plug into when the session expires, but I didn't find anything that looked straightfoward, possibly because a session might expire days before the next time a PHP page is called.)

Comment: ok this is fine and i did it previously.Now what my problem is when user clears the cache or session is timed out I cannot delete the row from database on session destruction.Will u help on that??

Comment: @soulpower if you have specifed only earlier that u did  like that then why ask again the question you should have been specific about your question . i mean think before you ask .

Comment: I don't see why that's necesary. If you're using the creation of a new token to automatically invalidate the previous ones, and the user logs in, gets a new token, and then the session times out, then the user loses the valid token -- it no longer exists outside of your database. They come back to log in, and are issued a new token. No problems. The only reason why you'd need to update the database is if you want to know who's logged in... but that wasn't a requirement.

Comment: Yeah my requirement is just to avoid the user from logging in from two different browsers or system.I used the token system just like u said bu it gives error while logging in from another browser and lets user login.Will you give some better idea????

Comment: It gives an error but lets the user log in? That's not very specific, or helpful. I'll edit my response with some pseudocode.

Comment: I tried your pseudocode.While i login for first time it is ok.Now i again try to login through another browser it again generates new token and lets me log in again???What i need is not to allow me to login second time.can you help???????

Comment: No. That's how it's supposed to work, and how I described it. I recommend that you avoid preventing a user from logging in if you think they're already logged in. I'm going to update again to make it more clear, explain why, and provide an alternative.

Comment: Yeah I m having that problem.So can we force the system to logout if the user logs in from different system or browser??

Comment: You want the system to logout the previous session if the user logs in from a different browser? By generating a new token (which you say it does) and always checking the token on page access, then you have it working..

Answer (score 0):

You can have a flag in mysql table like `login_staus`. Set to `1` if user logged in else set into `0`. Based on the flag you can do further. Also this is not the only way, check with others ans.

Comment: What happens if the user can't log out? How will she be able to log in to a new session?

Comment: @JamesS - that's why i have mentioned that this is not the only way, he/she may process your way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can add a flag(field) in table which has users.
When user logs in, set the flag. i.e. make it 1.
Before allowing any user to login, just check whether the flag is 1 or 0.
Allow user to login only if respective flag is 0.

Answer (score 0):

i would that it via mysql

by

```
creating a filed in user table wtih column logged_in

when user logs in update that to 1 

 when he logs outs set it to 0
```

and whenver user logs in just check that if the value of logged_in exists or not

it just an idea and i think it work without any issues of cookies or session

since you are referiiing to differnt computer and different browser

Comment: this can be made more specific by tracking use location from ip and informing him of unaauorized acess just like the facebook and gmail does . like sending him a mail :)